# primefaces dialog box and datatable checkbox selection

Tags: jsf-2, checkbox, primefaces, datatable, dialog

I want to display the selected rows of a table in a dialog box but I have an empty  dialog box even if I check one or more line nothing is displayed .. I realy don't know what is the cause of my problem .. I hope there will be someone who can help me (I m a beginner in jsf2 and I just discovered primefaces I really want help thanks soo much in advance ) this is my jsf :

```
  <p:outputLabel for="product" value="" />
        <p:dataTable id="product" var="ligne" value="#{productBean.myProducts}" selection="#{productBean.selectedProducts}" style="margin-bottom:0" rowKey="#{productBean.id}">

         <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
         <p:column headerText="Code">
        <h:outputText value="#{ligne.code}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="designation" >
        <h:outputText value="#{ligne.title}" />
        </p:column>
      <f:facet name="footer">
       <p:commandButton process="product" update=":form:multiProductDetail" icon="ui-icon-search" value="View" oncomplete="PF('multiProductDialog').show()" />
   </f:facet>
   </p:dataTable>
   <p:dialog header="Products" widgetVar="multiProductDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false" width="200">
   <p:outputPanel id="multiProductDetail" style="text-align:center;">
       <ui:repeat value="#{prodBean.selectedProducts}" var="ligne">
           <h:outputText value="#{ligne.code} -- #{ligne.title}" style="display:block"/>
       </ui:repeat>
   </p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Ok @BalusC .. I hvae already seen the MCVE link .. my problem is that I have followed an example from shwocases (primefaces.org) but my code doesn't work..I don't know where is the problem I have a new project with no error and I don't know wich part in my jsf caused the problem..I m really sorry if I waste your time and thank you soo much for your help

Comment: No it's only an inatention error ..I change this in my code..and it still not working :\

Comment: I really need help .. I don't ask question in this forum untill I can't find a solution by myself :\ I would be grateful to anyone who will share with me some of his knowledges and agreed to help me

Comment: I'd start with posting your getter for `selectedProducts` here, then also moving the `<p:dialog/>` out of the current `<h:form/>` and embedding an `<h:form/>` inside the dialog. Also make sure that your selection is actually populating the selectedProducts list

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you put a
 h:form 
inside this page

Is there data inside selection="#{productBean.selectedProducts}" .Can you a debug point there and see or put some sysouts in the getters and setters of selectedProducts.

Can you share your product code and check if selectedProducts is null or not
system.out.println("products"+selectedProducts.get(0))

best
vj

Comment: thank you soo much @vijayakumar gopalakrishn I really dont know if there is data inside selectedProducts .. and I thinks it is the origin of problem .. but I don't know how to check this

Comment: yes I have a <h:form  id="form">I have put a system.out.println("products"+selectedProducts.get(0)) in the setter of selectedProducts and then I have this problem : WARNING: javax.el.ELException: /list.xhtml @26,173 selection="#{productBean.selectedProducts}": java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: @Akino, why have you accepted an answer that doesn't solve your problem? You do realize this is misleading to anyone else who may be experiencing the same problem as you are?